# What's a simple way to check if a character is one of multiple characters in c?

Tags: c, string

I want to check which character c is either '+' or '-'. For this, I checked `strchr("+-", c)`.

But I'm not sure if this expression means the same as `if(c=='+'||c=='-')`.

These two mean the same thing, is there any problem if I fix it like `strchr("+-", c)`?

Comment: Anything wrong with `if (c == '+' || c=='-')`?

Comment: Is ‘switch’ simple in your book?

Comment: What *is* the "intended result"? What is the *actual* result? Do you have a proper [mcve] to show us?

Comment: `strchr("+-". c)` without the `!` would work.  `strchr` returns NULL when the character is *not* in the string.  It's probably less efficient than alternatives, though.

Comment: I have used `strchr` for this.  It can work fine, although the usage deserves a comment in your code, because it's kinda goofy-looking, doesn't immediately suggest what it's for.

Comment: @NateEldredge Oh yes. That's my mistake. Sorry for the confusion. I editted my question.

Comment: The edit, does it fix the problem you're asking about, or was it a typo in the question itself? If it fixed your problem you should ask @kn05 to write a proper answer, not edit your question to remove the problem and make comments (and possible answers) together with the whole question itself moot.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude After reading the comments, I realized that what I was asking wasn't clear. I've modified the question to fit the original intent of what I was trying to ask.

Comment: @NateEldredge `strchr("+-". c)` match 3 values.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Fair point, though I suspect in the majority of use cases, `c` is already known to be nonzero.

Comment: @NateEldredge Fair that `c` is likely non-zero.  OP did say _any problem_?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check which character c is either '+' or '-'. For this, I checked `strchr("+-", c)`

`strchr("+-", c)` returns non-`NULL` in 3 cases: `c=='+'`, `c=='-'`, `c=='\0'`.  Not quite the same as `c=='+'||c=='-'`.

Comment: Actually `if` is better in the OPs case.